# How to create offline map in Android?

Tags: android-maps

I want to create an offline map application in Android. I found that it is possible by using Mobile Atlas creator with Open Street Map. Later I found that Mobile Atlas creator is not supporting Open Street Map (Mapink option while creating zip file). I want to know the correct procedure to create an offlin Map. I would be very thankful for you if u provide me a tutorial link.. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I did this:

- create an Osmdroid ZIP atlas, using Mobile Atlas Creator
- rename the your zip file "tiles.zip"
- create in the phone storage a folder named osmdroid and copy the zip file there
- import in your android project the Osmdroid library (latest version at this moment 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.1@aar' )
  in your activity xml file add: `<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:clickable="true" />`
- in your java file add this:
  `private MapView mapView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
      mapView.setClickable(true);
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
      mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
      mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
  }`

It should work :)